# _this.props.removeFromFavs is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the main component theres a function

```
  removeFromFavs = id => {
    console.log("removed", id);
  };
```

which is then passed down through props

```
                      <CharacterList
                        characters={this.state.characters}
                        search={this.state.search}
                        nextCharacter={this.state.charactersNext}
                        prevCharacter={this.state.charactersPrev}
                        fetchSomeData={this.fetchSomeData}
                        scroll={this.scroll}
                        updateFavsState={this.updateFavsState}
                        closeMenu={this.closeMenu}
                        removeFromFavs={this.removeFromFavs}
                      />
```

then is passed another level deep through props, finally to where it'll be used.

```
      <Character
        key={index}
        character={c}
        updateFavsState={this.props.updateFavsState}
        location={this.props.location}
        removeFromFavs={this.props.removeFromFavs}
      />
```

in the Character component there is a function

```
  handleClick = location => {
    if (location === "/favorites") {
      this.props.removeFromFavs(this.props.character.id);
    } else {
      this.props.updateFavsState(this.props.character);
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        loved: !prevState.loved
      }));
    }
  };
```

that is then called in an onClick event

```
                onClick={() => {
                  this.handleClick(this.props.location.pathname);
                }}
```

I'm receiving this error that it's not a function.

What i really dont understand is how the function "updateFavsState"
is passed through exactly the same way and is executed the same but i'm not getting an error for that one

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
onClick={this.handleClick(this.props.location.pathname)}
```

You're not needing inline arrow function because you're not passing event in handleClick. It's just a handler.

Comment: this is continually calling the function in a loop, i've got an endless amount of alerts popping up

Comment: Now, this is a separate error. You noticed the function is being called. Hold on, I will check what's going on there.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt with the use of setState. You have both updateFavsState and setState. With your current code, can't say what's going on there at all. You may debug that.